# Magnetic field loops do not knot or link

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, topology

The magnetic field is composed of closed loops (assuming there is no magnetic monopole). How does one prove any two magnetic loops do not [knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory) to form a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(knot_theory))?

Comment: What makes you think they can't form knots?

Comment: @Hans It's obviously not true if there is magnetic material (long bendy magnet) or conductive material (long bendy solenoid) present that can be tied in a knot. This presumably includes plasma.  But I'm guessing it has to be true in any empty volume where the field has to obey the Laplace equation.

Comment: You are both right. I am embarrassed by my stupid question.

Comment: @RogerWood There seem to be some papers about knotted and linked vacuum solutions to Maxwell's equations, like [arXiv:1502.01382](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01382).

Comment: @benrg: You seem to have answered my new question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602923/17354.Care to provide a detailed answer there?

Comment: @benrg I haven't tried to understand the details of that paper, but isn't it saying that E and H can be knotted together rather than H and H?

Comment: @RogerWood - The long bendy solenoid with vacuum in the interior - isn't that empty space with boundary conditions?

Comment: @RogerWood: I just started reading the paper. You may be looking at the figures, such as Figure 1. They are indeed not very clear on the point of link. However, it is shown clearer in Figure 2. of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0342.pdf.

Comment: @mmesser314 Hah, you're right.  Now I wish I hadn't thrown away my Slinky. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slinky

Comment: @Hans Yes, that's clearer.  The bendy solenoid is interesting in that you can set up whatever contorted field lines you want then switch off the current and watch it evolve.  Presumably you can run this backwards too with a suitable starting condition.  I'm still dubious there's a static knotty solution in a simple convex volume.

Comment: @RogerWood - Instead of a solenoid, use a wire loop. With a magnetic, you can induce a current in the wire, and the current will induce a magnetic field around the wire. The magnetic field will be toroidal. Field lines will be circles around the wire. Now put the wire inside the hollow solenoid. This adds a field component parallel to the wire. So the result is spiral magnetic field with slinky shaped field lines.

Comment: @RogerWood: Agree with using bendy solenoids. Is it necessary to switch off the current? You can make the current time dependent like an antenna. Does the field lines from two linked toroidal solenoids with time constant currents count as "static solution"?

Comment: @mmesser314: The field lines will be helical. Some may not even close on itself. So they may not knot or link.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't.

Take a set of short permanent magnets. Chain them together. Make a knot out of the chain, and connect the ends.

Or form two chains. Make them into linked closed loops.