# Can magnetic loops with no source current knot or link?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, topology

The answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602891/17354) is obviously no. I would like to pose a variation of that question. Suppose a simply connected domain of a 3-d vacuum space has no source current. Does there exist a case where two closed loops of magnetic field residing in that domain knot into a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(knot_theory))? (Either static or dynamic answer would be great.)

Comment: Is this question even well-defined? Seems to rely on notion of magnetic ferld lines, which are a visualization aid. Let's say uou are given a long spreadsheet with six columns: X, Y, Z, Bx, By, Bz (position and value of the field). How would you test knottedness?

Comment: There seem to be some papers about knotted and linked vacuum solutions to Maxwell's equations, like [arXiv:1502.01382](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01382), but I don't feel qualified to answer.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly. So if i choose to draw one line which is knotted i get one value of knottedness, and if i draw another line nearby, that follows the same trajectory, i get double? To define it properly one needs some sort of measure of knotedness and density thereoff. I am sure it is possible, but I am not sure such definition would be unique. I would love to see it though

Comment: Could also have min/max instead of integrals ...

Comment: @Cryo: How can "another line" presumably also closed follow the "same trajectory"?

Comment: @Hans. I would start the second line close enough to the first line, and rely on continuity of the field to lead to second line's trajectory to be the same as the first one + some perturbation  like displacement (which would not affect knotedness). When I said the 'same' trajectory, i meant it has the same knotedness, sorry

Comment: @Cryo: OK, but you are using the confusing phrase "the same" again. You mean homeomorphic. Yes, the two lines would have the same knottedness if there is no singularity in the Maxwell's equations. Moreover, I would like to have two loops linked.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly. Fair enough, but does it change my argument? How do you go from a continuous field to discrete field lines in an unambigous way? Do you care how strong the field is along the line? I guess, I was hoping to see a *generic* way to detect linkedness. And in abcence of such method, i think it is correct to say that question is not well-defined. Nevertheless thanks for a great answer below

Comment: @Cryo I deleted my earlier comments because they're obsolete. You're right that *detecting* linkedness is more challenging. My answer shamelessly avoids that tricky issue by considering a case where the linkedness is intuitively clear. :)

Comment: @Cryo: In which way is the question not well defined? The field lines are well defined. I am asking if there exists two field line loops that are linked. Which part of it is ambiguous, the generic method notwithstanding?

Comment: @Hans. I think it's my mistake. You have the answer that you were after, and I ended up switching the goal in my mind. Chiral Anomaly gave a great example of fields that are linked. What remain undefined is how to detect linkedness in a generic case, but that was not the point. Merry Christmas guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A magnetic field line is a line that is tangent to the magnetic field vector at every point along the line. The question asks if two magnetic field lines can be linked, if the magnetic field is consistent with Maxwell's equations in a vacuum. The answer is **yes**, which I'll prove by constructing an example.

### The example

In terms of the complex-valued field $\mathbf{F}\equiv\mathbf{E}+i\mathbf{B}$, Maxwell's equations in a vacuum can be written as a pair of equations
$$
\newcommand{\bfA}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\bfB}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\bfE}{\mathbf{E}}
\newcommand{\bfF}{\mathbf{F}}
\nabla\cdot\bfF=0
\hspace{2cm}
i\dot\bfF=\nabla\times\bfF.
$$
Any field that satisfies the first equation at time $t=0$ can be evolved in time using the second equation, and the first equation is equivalent to the pair of uncoupled equations $\nabla\cdot\bfB=0=\nabla\cdot\bfE$, so **the question reduces to this purely spatial question about the magnetic field** at time $t=0$: If the vector field $\bfB$ satisfies $\nabla\cdot\bfB=0$, then can two of its lines be linked?

If $\bfB=\nabla\times\bfA$ for some smooth nonsingular vector field $\bfA$, then we automatically have $\nabla\cdot\bfB=0$. We can use this fact to construct an example. Use a Cartesian coordinate system $x,y,z$, and use the abbreviations
$$
 f(x,y)\equiv x^2+y^2
\hspace{2cm}
 g(x,z)\equiv (x-1)^2+z^2
$$
and consider these two circles:

- Circle $C'$ is defined by $f(x,y)=1$ and $z=0$.
- Circle $C''$ is defined by $g(x,z)=1$ and $y=0$.

These circles are linked. The goal is to construct a field $\bfA$ such that both of these circles are everywhere tangent to the field $\bfB\equiv \nabla\times\bfA$, so that $C'$ and $C''$ are both lines of $\bfB$. To do this, write $\bfA=\bfA'+\bfA''$ with
$$
\bfA'=
\begin{cases}
 (0,0,(f(x,y))^{-1/2}) & \text{for }|f(x,y)-1|<0.001\text{ and }|z|<0.001\\
 (0,0,0) & \text{for } |f(x,y)-1| > 0.002\text{ or }|z|>0.002
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\bfA''=
\begin{cases}
 (0,(g(x,z))^{-1/2},0) & \text{for }|g(x,z)-1|<0.001\text{ and }|y|<0.001\\
 (0,0,0) & \text{for } |g(x,z)-1| > 0.002\text{ or }|y|>0.002,
\end{cases}
$$
and interpolate smoothly between $0.001$ and $0.002$ in each case. Then $\bfA'$ is nonzero only in a small neighborhood of $C'$, and $\bfA''$ is nonzero only in a small neighborhood of $C''$, and both $\bfA'$ and $\bfA''$ are smooth and nonsingular everywhere. This implies that $\bfB$ is smooth and nonsingular everywhere. Within the neighborhoods defined by the $0.001$ cutoff, the fields satisfy
\begin{align}
 \nabla\times\bfA' &\propto (f(x,y))^{-3/2}(y,-x,0) \\
 \nabla\times\bfA'' &\propto (g(x,z))^{-3/2}(z,0,-(x-1)),
\end{align}
and these are everywhere tangent to the circles $C'$ and $C''$, respectively. The supports of $\bfA'$ and $\bfA''$ do not overlap, so $\bfB\equiv\nabla\times(\bfA'+\bfA'')$ is also everywhere tangent to the circles $C'$ and $C''$, and these circles are linked. This completes the construction.

### The intuition that led to the example

Here's the intuition that led to the example. Consider two straight current-carrying wires $W'$ and $W''$, one on the line $x=y=0$ and one on the line $x-1=z=0$. The magnetic field produced by either one of these wires by itself has circular field lines centered on that wire. Let $\bfA'$ and $\bfA''$ be the corresponding vector potentials. Choose the circles $C'$ and $C''$ as above, and modify $\bfA'$ and $\bfA''$ to drop smoothly to zero as we move away from those respective circles, so that their supports don't overlap, and take the currents to be zero for consistency. Now take $\bfB$ to be the magnetic field with vector potential $\bfA'+\bfA''$, and we have two linked magnetic field lines in a magnetic field that is everywhere smooth and nonsingular and satisfies Maxwell's equations in a vacuum at $t=0$. What happens at $t\neq 0$ can be inferred from Maxwell's equations using this initial condition together with an additional initial condition on the electric field, but the question allows for a dynamic answer, so what happens at $t\neq 0$ is not important. The magnetic field lines are linked at $t=0$, at least.

### Can a magnetic field line form an arbitrary knot?

As Hans suggested in a comment, the idea described above can be simplified and generalized by using (temporary) solenoids instead of (temporary) individual wires. Take any knot drawn in 3d space, which may have multiple linked components. Replace the drawn line with a long-and-thin solenoid so that the original line coincides with a magnetic field line enclosed by the solenoid. Let $\bfA$ be the vector potential of the whole set-up, and modify $\bfA$ so that it falls rapidly but smoothly to zero away from the original drawn line.  For consistency with Maxwell's equations, also delete the current (the solenoid), because now $\bfA$ is zero in the space where the current was. Since $\bfA$ is still the same as before in a neighborhood of the drawn line, taking the curl of $\bfA$ will give a magnetic field that is well-defined everywhere, satisfies $\nabla\cdot\bfB=0$ everywhere, and has a line that coincides with the original drawn line.

Comment: Clever construction. +1 and accepted. It is similar to having two linked solenoids.

Comment: @Hans Now that you mention it, the linked-solenoids approach would have been easier! Start with two linked solenoids, let $A'$ and $A''$ be the gauge fields inside each one, set them smoothly to zero elsewhere (so that the currents can also be set to zero), and then take the curl of $A'+A''$. Boom. One-line proof. Your comment is better than my answer!

Comment: Well, the two formulations are homeomorphic so long as the solenoid currents are not singular. The essential point is that the supports of $\bf A$'s and $\bf B$'s are separate. What I am wondering is that what happens at sufficiently large $t$. Is the link structure invariant? I suppose the two supports propagate outward at light speed and remain separate. It would be interesting to ascertain whether the topology of the knots/links remains invariant for Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 2):

As @benrg mentioned in his comment, there are papers on exactly this topic, e.g.,

1. [Carlos Hoyos, Nilanjan Sircar and Jacob Sonnenschein, New knotted solutions of Maxwell’s equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01382).
2. [Hridesh Kedia, Iwo Bialynicki-Birula, Daniel Peralta-Salas,
   and William T.M. Irvine, Tying knots in light fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0342).

There, the electromagnetic field is constructed using the Batesman's constuct, where the fields $({\bf E},{\bf B})$ is encoded by the Riemann-Silberstein vector
$${\bf F = E}+ i{\bf B}=\nabla\alpha\times\nabla\beta$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex functions of $(t,x,y,z)$ and $i$ is the imaginary unit. This is then substituted in to the Maxwell's equations to obtain an equation constraining $(\alpha,\beta)$. The solutions of linked field lines are then constructed through some transformations such as conformal mapping.